# How to learn DirectShow Encoder/decoder programming?

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, directshow.net

I have created a project using **directShow** that takes the captured video from a webcam and preview it. 
Now I want to encode on run time video captured alive and save it on desk then play it back I want to use it as part from my code(dll for example) not a standalone part.

Any links can help me to get how to do that please I am in search process for a week and feel not understood with the methodology?

Answer (score 3):

If you're writting new app, or you're interested in learn about video processing you should consider using [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
DirectShow is an 'obsolete' and shortly will be discontinued technology.

If despite this, you're still interested in DirectShow, you could start with [MSDN DirectShow Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Examples are in C++ but the idea is the same).

As short summary you must understand this concepts.

- What is a **DirectShow Filter**, and wich types exists (Source,Transform,Renderers and Capture).[Introduction to DirectShow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- How can I connect multiple Filters in a **Graph**,how filters are connected between them, and how I can control the playback. Start with [Building the Filter Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Some utils that can help you:

- [DirectShow Graph Spy DLL](http://alax.info/blog/777) Allows to watch Graphs created by others app
- [Monogram Graph Studio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) Improved version of Microsoft Graph Edit.

**NOTE:** As you tagged this post with 'C#' and 'Directshow.NET' tags, I will consider that you're using DirectShow.NET library (the unofficial port of DirectShow to .NET).

Comment: If I follow your recommendation about MF what will be best way to learn it